# Simultaneous Congruence of Two Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could you please let me know an answer to the following question on simultaneous congruence of two matrices. This question came up while trying to handle a system of PDE.

**QUESTION:**

Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, let $A$ be symmetric and let $B$ skew-symmetric. It is known that

**i) Sylvester's Theorem:** $A$ is congruent to $D$ i.e. for some $Q\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, $Q^t A Q=D$, where $$D:=\operatorname*{diag}\left(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{p\text{-times}},\underbrace{-1,\ldots,-1}_{q\text{-times}},\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{(n-p-q)\text{-times}}\right),$$ where $p,q$ stand for the number of positive and negative eigenvalues of $A$, respectively.

**ii) Darboux Theorem:** $B$ is congruent to $J_m$ i.e. for some $R\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, $R^t B R=J_m$, where $$J_m:=\operatorname*{diag}\left(\underbrace{\left(
                                 \begin{array}{cc}
                                   0 & 1 \\
                                   -1 & 0 \\
                                 \end{array}
                               \right),\ldots,\left(
                                 \begin{array}{cc}
                                   0 & 1 \\
                                   -1 & 0 \\
                                 \end{array}
                               \right)}_{m\text{-times}},0,\ldots,0
\right),$$ where $\operatorname*{rank}B=2m$.

When is $A,B$ simultaneously congruent i.e. there exists a $P\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$P^t A P =D\text{ and }P^t B P = J_m?$$ 
Is there any necessary and sufficient condition?

Comment: Consider checking this paper by Sergeichuk (particularly section 2.2): http://dx.doi.org/10.1070/IM1988v031n03ABEH001086.